# Javascript/jQuery - DateTime to Date and Time separate strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any simple way to convert the following:

```
2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z
```

In to UK date format: `31-08-2011`

and time to: `20:01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z").toLocaleDateString();
// date = 2011/08/31

date = date.split("/");
// date = ["31", "08, "2011"]    

date = date[2] + "-" + (date[0].length == 1 ? "0" + date[0] : date[0]) + "-" + (date[1].length == 1 ? "0" + date[1] : date[1]);
// data = 2011-31-08

$("#your-txtbox").val(date);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use momentjs (http://momentjs.com/):

```
var date = moment(dateObject).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var time = moment(dateObject).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jquery-dateFormat plugin](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat). The following should do the trick:

```
$.format.date('2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z', "dd-MM-yyyy"));
$.format.date('2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z', "hh:mm"));
```

Answer (score 4):

**Date**:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var date = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
$('#date1').html(date + '-' + month + '-' + year);
```

**Time**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tick;

  function stop() {
    clearTimeout(tick);
  }

  function clock() {
    var ut=new Date();
    var h,m,s;
    var time="";
    h=ut.getHours();
    m=ut.getMinutes();
    s=ut.getSeconds();
    if(s<=9) s="0"+s;
    if(m<=9) m="0"+m;
    if(h<=9) h="0"+h;
    time+=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=time;
    tick=setTimeout("clock()",1000); 
  }
</script>
<body onload="clock();" onunload="stop();"> 
  <p><span id="clock"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = '2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z';
var b = new Date(a);
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for methods you can use on b now.

Comment: on IE8: `new Date('2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z')` does not works. It's return `NaN`. Fix is requiered to do this in IE8 and older.

Answer (score 2):

```
var rg=/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\..*/g;
var dateStr="2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z".replace(rg,"$3-$2-$1"); // result is 31-08-2011
var timeStr="2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z".replace(rg,"$4:$5"); // result is 20:01
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [date object](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format):

```
d = new Date('2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z');
date = d.format("dd-mm-yyyy");
time = d.format("HH:MM");
```

Comment: You are right, it's not. But if you follow the link you see a function extending Date with a format function. Sorry, I should have mention that.

Comment: on IE8: `new Date('2011-08-31T20:01:32.000Z')` does not works. It's return `NaN`. Fix is requiered to do this in IE8 and older.