# Laravel Eloquent returns wrong created_at and updated_at values

Tags: php, laravel

I am retrieving data from a MySQL database. The `created_at` and `updated_at` value in the database is different from what I got when I tried to query the data using Eloquent.

I have tried setting the timezone by using `date_default_timezone_set()` but the problem still persists.

Here is the query in my Controller,

```
$a = FooModel::whereDate('created_at', '=', $date);
```

In my case, `date` is `date("Y-m-d")`

The value of `created_at` in the database is `2019-07-22 13:00:17` but the value of `created_at` in `$a` is `2019-07-23 00:00:17`

This also applies to `updated_at`

Comment: You might have different timezones on your server/Laravel/PHP configurations and the database. What is `$date`? Are you certain that you are looking at the correct row in the DB?

Comment: Fix the timezone in config and also try Carbon for getting date

Comment: I really think that the problem is on timezone configurations but when I try to check Carbon::now(), it returns the correct timezone. Maybe the problem is deeper than these configurations?

Comment: I also don't have config/app.php . I only have bootstrap/app.php but I don't know where to put the timezone configs in

Comment: can you share screenshot of database table values?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by creating my own timestamps, DO NOT use the `$table->timestamps()`
on your migration create your own timestamp instead like: `$table->timestamp('created_on')`

I figured out that laravel is doing something upon retrieving the default `created_at` and `updated_at` I dont know what it is but, that's why if you were to get their value on the database it returns same date(mostly) but different time.

also make sure to disable the default timestamps on your model by using: `public $timestamps = false;` if you were to make your own timestamp.

Comment: I just tried what you say and the date still appears wrong, the solution does not work

Comment: I dont know what version of laravel you were using, have you tried configuring your `timezone`? its located on your config/app.php

Comment: Hello Darwin, I use Laravel 8, yes I have configured 'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
There are two solutions for me:

1 - Convert date:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566257/3919435and-time-separate-strings

2- Add In model method:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429890/222142